# Using Pasmo on Chūō Line (Rapid)

Tags: tickets, public-transport, tokyo

Can you use a Pasmo to tap in and out when traveling between Kichijōji Station and Ochanomizu Station on the Chūō Line (Rapid)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Pasmo, Suica, and other IC cards can be used virtually anywhere in the greater Tokyo area. The Chūō line is one of the important backbones of the area, and yes, accepts IC cards on its entire length.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add to the already perfect answer, you can use the Suica, Pasmo, or any of the [10 interoperable IC cards](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e2359_003.html) on the Chuo Line within the entire Tokyo Suburban Area, which entails the entirety of the Chuo Main Line from Tokyo up to Matsumoto.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on my own question having been to Tokyo, Yes, I used pasmo on the Chūō Line.

There was no practical difference between using the Tokyo metro lines (the ones with a single letter symbols on transit maps) and using the JR commuter lines (the ones with J? symbols on transit maps).